# dropping a postgres role

Tags: postgresql

I am  struggling with dropping a ready only user I created on one of the database in the cluster. I created a read only user using following script:

```
CREATE USER is_user_readonly WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'test1';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE db1 to is_user_readonly;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public to is_user_readonly;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO is_user_readonly;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO is_user_readonly;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO is_user_readonly;
```

I logged in database db1 and created this user is_user_readonly. I logged in as admin. This user is created on all databases in the cluster.

Now, for dropping this user, I logged in db1 as admin and ran below scripts:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE db1 FROM is_user_readonly;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public FROM is_user_readonly;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM is_user_readonly;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public FROM is_user_readonly;
REVOKE USAGE ON SCHEMA public FROM is_user_readonly;
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE db1 FROM is_user_readonly;
```

At this point I am really pulling out my hair that there is still some dependency.

```
SQL Error [2BP01]: ERROR: role "is_user_readonly" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
Detail: privileges for default privileges on new relations belonging to role isadmin in schema public
ERROR: role "is_user_readonly" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
Detail: privileges for default privileges on new relations belonging to role isadmin in schema public
ERROR: role "is_user_readonly" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
Detail: privileges for default privileges on new relations belonging to role isadmin in schema public.
```

Do I need to run the revoke script on all database in this cluster?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Revoke the default privileges:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE whatever IN SCHEMA public
   REVOKE SELECT ON TABLES FROM is_user_readonly;
```

The role `whatever` here is the user you were logged in as when you ran the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` statement.

Comment: Thank you, Laurenz Albe! That worked like a charm. This saved me so many hours of research. Highly appreciate it.